# mui icon not rendering when React app is deployed

Tags: reactjs, deployment, material-ui, vercel, surge.sh

In my app I'm importing a mui/icon:

```
import PriceCheckIcon from "@mui/icons-material/PriceCheck";
```

When I run the app locally the icon displays fine but once deployed on Surge nothing shows, and no errors.
Then I tried to deploy with Vercel and had the same issue.
Has anyone experienced this before or would know why it isn't displaying. I do have a condition for it to display which is when I get a 502.

This is my condition if that helps:

```
<span
            style={
              Price > cinemaWorldPrice ? { color: "green" } : { color: "red" }
            }
          >
            {error && Price > cinemaWorldPrice ? (
              <PriceCheckIcon />
            ) : (
              <CurrencyFormat
                value={cinemaWorldPrice}
                displayType={"text"}
                prefix={"$"}
                decimalScale={2}
                fixedDecimalScale
              />
            )}
          </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can run this command:

```js
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

and this should be working fine.

Comment: I have already run this command. The icon is rendering locally but just not once deployed.